# How to change the colour of font within a WP8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, fonts, colors

I'm developing a WP8 application for the Visually Impaired and I am trying to be able to change the color of the font within the application. I no there is not an API for this to help me. What i am trying to do is that there will be a list of colors in a longlistselector and the user can select a color and the entire application font color changes. I am not the best programmer in the world as I have just started and this application is going towards one of my family members. The part I'm stuck on is trying to change it, I can select it but It goes nowhere after that, any pointers or tips would be great.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    font.Add(new Theme1() { ThemeText = "White", ThemeFontSize = "40" });
    font.Add(new Theme1() { ThemeText = "Green", ThemeFontSize = "40" });
    font.Add(new Theme1() { ThemeText = "Blue", ThemeFontSize = "40" });

    LLsFontList.ItemsSource = font;
}


private void LLsFontList_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (LLsFontList != null && LLsFontList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
       var selectedItem = LLsFontList.SelectedItem as Theme1;
       SayWords(selectedItem.ThemeText + "\r\n");
       var id = selectedItem.ThemeText.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

this is where I get stuck, should I be sending this call to a resource file so it changes the whole application.

Comment: But how do you apply your theme to text? What is Theme1 class?

Comment: theme 1 class is where all the set's and get's are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is not the most elegant, but I hope this will get you going.

Okay, here's how your Theme class should look like:

```
public class Theme : INotifyPropertyChanged      
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private string themeText;
public string ThemeText
{
    get
    {
        return themeText;
    }
    set
    {
        themeText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ThemeText");
    }
}

private int fontSize;
public int FontSize
{
    get
    {
        return fontSize;
    }
    set
    {
        fontSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FontSize");
    }
}

private Brush fontColor;
public Brush FontColor
{
    get
    {
        return fontColor;
    }
    set
    {
        fontColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FontColor");
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}   
}
```

Then create bindings between your textblocks and object of Theme class:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{Binding ThemeText}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="{Binding FontColor}"/>
```

And about code-behind: you should have a global Theme object with some default values:

```
Theme theme = new Theme
{
    ThemeText = "Red",
    FontColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    FontSize = 40
};
```

Then set DataContext of your TextBlock to it(inside page constructor):

```
TextBlock.DataContext = theme;
```

And if you want to change it, just do it this way:

```
theme.ThemeText = "Blue";
theme.FontColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
theme.FontSize = 60;
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask them.